# How to model this simple relationship in a database schema?

Tags: database, database-design

**The relevant information:**

> University Subject
>
> Semester offered
>
> Campus

Illuminating example:

> Subject ABC123 is offered in Semester 1 at Campus X, and in Semester 2 at
>   Campus Y.

How would I model this relationship as table definitions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

University (1 - m) campus

Subject (m - m) campus (And in this many to many relational table you will store the semester id as well)

If you do not want to work with many universities then . . . .

```
Subject_Campus_Semester (subject_id, campus_id, semester_id)

Subject(subject_id, subject_name, ...)

Campus(campus_id, campus_name, ...)

Semester(semester_id, semester_name, ...)
```